# Virtualenv created a folder, but the result its not I wanted

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I created a folder via virtualenv command, but the result isn't what I wanted.

```
[root@localhost opt]# virtualenv my_env
New python executable in /opt/my_env/bin/**python2.6**
Also creating executable in /opt/my_env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

My system is CentOS 6.5. Before I created my folder I upgraded my python 2.6 to python 3.6. Then I wanted to create an isolated environment to practice Django. Unfortunately, the folder has python 2.6, it should be python 3.6. 
Can someone tell me what happened?

Comment: Please format the error by adding 4 leading space to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using `-p` option? as in:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 venv
```

Comment: I've tried, it works. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

> I upgraded my python 2.6 to python 3.6

In the Python universe, Python 2 and Python 3 are two different things. So what you actually did was to install Python 3 alongside Python 2. Now your system has both Python 2 (which can be run by the command `python`) and also Python 3 (which can be run by the command `python3`)

So when you ran `virtualenv my_env` it fired the default Python interpreter which is Python 2 in CentOS 6.x. That's the reason for Python 2.6 in your virtual environment.

**Setting up Virtual Environment with Python 3**

To get a Python 3 interpreter in your virtual environment run:

```
virtualenv -p python3 my_env
```

Comment: It works, I appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could go with `python3 -m venv env`
No need for `virtualenv`

What you did

```
virtualenv my_env
```

is invoking the python2 `virtualenv` command to prepare a python2 environment.

Besides, you should have a look at 
[Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/)

Comment: I am a new guys in programming! Thank you for you help, I appreciated you.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are on linux and many programs will start to use python3 as default, you can create an alias for python2 and 3 in order to virtually switch the default python to python3 in your system. To do that, just add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
alias python2='/usr/bin/python'
```

This will make it easy to work with the latest Django version while not breaking any current python program from running. And it's easy to undo.
Scripts can start with `#!/usr/bin/python3` or `#!/usr/bin/python` to respectively use python3 or python2 directly.